# Importing a module in a script

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, import, module

So, I have been working in the jupyter lab and I have created a code that uses numpy.

In the jupyter I had no problem using numpy. I installed the library, and I used the command import to use such module.

However, I had to save my code as a py file. When I try to run my py file using my cmd, I receive this message:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

If i type in my cmd "pip show numpy" it shows me that I have numpy installed.

I also have tried to add to my code a line with:

> pip install numpy

> pip3 install numpy

> python -m pip install numpy

> python3 -m pip install numpy

> conda install -c anaconda numpy

> conda install numpy

and for every option I received a syntax error:

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Can someone help me?

Comment: My guess is that your python (.py) code doesn't use the same venv as your Jupyter notebook. Make sure that you are in the same venv when you are working (or if you are using conda, then make sure that you activated conda env)

Comment: Can you show your full code/how you are importing numpy?

Comment: @eemamedo And how do I do that?

Comment: @ThiagoLobo https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Jupyter+venv

Comment: @ThiagoLobo so, it seems like you are using conda (based on your question). Check the kernel in your Jupyter notebook -> pip list. You will probably get `numpy` as installed. Then for your .py, do `conda activate name_of_the_kernel` -> pip list. Check if numpy is there.

Comment: @eemamedo I think you were right.

I figured it out that when I was using my jupyterlab, I was doing so by using anaconda.

After a I saved my code as a py file, it was running directly from the python that I have installed in my computer.

So I openened my cmd and installed numpy. It worked. Thank you.

Comment: And just so you know, everything listed below "I also have tried to add to my code a line with",  are command line-based commands, & not python code. And so you cannot just embed them in a Python `.py` script file. Over in Jupyter, there's automagics enabled by default commonly and so that is why it seems you can execute some command line code in what appears at a glance to be the Python kernel where you can run Python in other cells. The thing is though Jupyter is being smart & behind the scenes adding `%` in front of pip/conda and using the modern magic install commands inside a notebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments section, it seems like your Python script (`.py`) was not using the correct environment. Please ensure that correct virtual environment is selected by doing `conda activate name_of_the_kernel`, where `name_of_the_kernel` should match the kernel used in your Jupyter notebook.